# Change grid lines interval in mplstereonet

Tags: matplotlib, polar-coordinates

Everytime I plot stereograms using grid, the grid lines are spaced for every 30 degrees (like below). Is there a way to set grid lines every 10 degrees? I'm using `mplstereonet`´

It used to be every 10 degrees, as the examples shown in the github page https://github.com/joferkington/mplstereonet

[image]

My MWE:

```
import pandas as pd
import mplstereonet as mpl

strike = [120,145,150]
dip = [30,44,72]

f, ax = mpl.subplots()
ax.pole(strike, dip)
ax.grid()
ax._polar.set_position(ax.get_position())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grid lines are set according to the `ax.xticks` and `ax.yticks`.
Note that both axis dimensions are expressed in radians.

Here is an option (adding `numpy` dependency)

```py
import pandas as pd
import mplstereonet as mpl
import numpy as np

strike = [120,145,150]
dip = [30,44,72]

f, ax = mpl.subplots()
ax.pole(strike, dip)
ax.grid(ls=":")  # Similar style as the example provided 

ymin, ymax = ax.get_ylim()
xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()

# Create x and y ticks every 10°
y_ticks = np.arange(ymin, ymax, np.deg2rad(10))
x_ticks = np.arange(ymin, ymax, np.deg2rad(10))

ax.set_xticks(x_ticks)
ax.set_yticks(y_ticks)
```

[image]